# React: How to separate login/signup page from appearing among the rest of the app content

Tags: reactjs, react-router

In my react app, whenever i'm accessing the **SignIn** or **SignOut** page/route in my `react admin app`, the **SignIn/SignOut** page appears on the main body section of the app alongside the sidebar and header section.

I have tried to solve that by changing my routes but nothing happens.

**app.js**

```
// HOC
import Layout from "./hocs/Layout"
const App = () => {
    return (
      <Router>
        <Layout>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/login" component={SignIn} />  <==== SignIn/Login route
            <PrivateRoute
              exact
              path="/Dashboard"
              component={ContentComponent}
            />
            <Route exact path="/signup" component={SignUp} />
            <Route exact path="/reset-password" component={ResetPassword} />
            <Route exact path="/activate/:uid/:token" component={Activate} />
            <PrivateRoute exact path="/Customers" component={CustomerDetails} />
            <Route component={NotFound} />
          </Switch>
        </Layout>
      </Router>
    );
  }

export default App;
```

**Layout** file

```
const Layout = (props) => {

  return (
        <Fragment>
          <Row className={css(styles.container)}>
            {isAuthenticated ? authLinks : ""}

            <Column flexGrow={1} className={css(styles.mainBlock)}>
              <Column>
                <HeaderComponent
                  title={selectedItem}
                  className={css(styles.header)}
                />

                <div className="content">{props.children}</div> <==== CONNECT TO APP.js

              </Column>
            </Column>
          </Row>
        </Fragment>
  );
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  auth: state.auth,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { checkAuthenticated, load_user })(
  Layout
);
```

Below is the image. Obviously the signup page should't be on the same page as content rather on a separate page.

[image]

Comment: Where are you targeting to place the SignIn & SignUp components then? Currently you are appending them all to `.content`

Comment: In a separate page that not linked to the content of the page. Check the updated post containing the image

Comment: Stupid question: why do you have that `{` and `<Fragment>` in `Layout`?  They seem meaningless.

Comment: I found that mistake and removed it.

Comment: Also, you didn't include the `import` line, but is `<Router>` a Router or a *Browser*Router?

Comment: It is ``import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";``

Comment: Can you please include your `PrivateRoute` code?  I'm actually starting to expect that it's the problem: it's the only non-route there, and if I understand correctly `/Dashboard` is the second component rendering with your signup dialog.  I suspect there's a bug in it making it always render.

Answer (score 0):

I'd have some conditions as to check whether the user is logged in or not etc. As I understand, the `Layout` component should only be for logged in users. Therefore, if the user is not logged in you should not be rendering it

```
{isLoggedIn === false && (
    // render login component here
)}
```

If user is logged in, that is the time you can show the `Layout` component

```
{isLoggedIn && <Layout></Layout>}
```

Example: https://codesandbox.io/s/new-wildflower-1scxg?file=/src/App.js

Comment: That's (presumably) what `PrivateRoute` does, but the core issue here isn't with blocking routes using state; it's that a React Router `<Switch>` is rendering two pages. I'd argue a correct solution would have to address *that* (although I do think the problem *is* likely related to OP's `PrivateRoute`).

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are somehow rendering the second component inside `Layout` (eg. if your `HeaderComponent` was actually rendering the second component), the problem has to be with your `PrivateRoute` component.  In this code:

```
<Router>
    <Layout>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/login" component={SignIn} />
        <PrivateRoute
          exact
          path="/Dashboard"
          component={ContentComponent}
        />
```

If `PrivateRoute` was just a `Route` tag there would be no way you could see `SignIn` and `ContentComponent` at the same time, because the way React-Router and the `<Switch>` tag work is that they only render one component at a time.

Ergo, logic dictates (again, unless `Layout` or something in it is broken) that `PrivateRoute` *isn't* just:

```
const PrivateRoute = () => <Route>...</Route>;
```

... because it *can't be*: if it was you wouldn't see both components :)

Since you didn't include the `PrivateRoute` code I can't say for sure what the problem is, but again if you simplify it down starting with a `Route` ... or fix whatever logic wraps your `Route` inside `PrivateRoute` ... that should fix your issue.